# git: using --since does not show all the commits I want to see

Tags: git

I'm using this:

```
git log --since="3 months ago"
```

but it just shows me the last 8 commits (done more or less during the last two months).

I have a much more bigger list of commits as I can see from my bitbucket account...So how can I see them from my terminal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` will only show commits that are direct ancestors of the current `HEAD` (the commit you have checked out), so it may not be showing the commits you expect because they are on other branches.

You can add the `--all` flag to `git log` so that it will show commits on all branches:

```
git log --all --since='3 months ago'
```

If the commits in bitbucket were pushed by someone else, then it's also possible that you haven't fetched them yet, so you may want to run `git fetch` first to make sure your remote-tracking branches are up-to-date.

Comment: @georgebrok thanks, but it was my fault: I just was not using the down arrow to see the rest of the logs..:) Just 'git log' show the logs I want to see.

Comment: well, exactly, FYI, 'git log' shows the commits before the current commit you are using..And 'git log --all' shows all the commits.